# Eclipse (STS) Welcome dash board error - Unable to see welcome dash board

Tags: eclipse, dashboard

when I am trying start STS (Spring Tool Suite) I am getting this error:

> Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".

This is my .log file in the workspace .metadata directory:

```
!SESSION 2014-08-12 09:02:22.701 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.5.1.201405030657-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

This is a continuation of log file D:\newstsworkspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2014-08-12 09:03:00.459
!SESSION 2014-08-12 09:02:22.701 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=3.5.1.201405030657-RELEASE-e43
java.version=1.7.0
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-08-12 09:03:00.460
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-08-12 09:05:15.347
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-08-12 09:05:15.348
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Geek Labs'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-08-12 09:05:30.927
!MESSAGE Unable to create part

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 1 2014-08-12 09:05:30.928
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui.actions.ShowDashboardPageAction$1.runInUIThread(ShowDashboardPageAction.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener cannot be found by org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser_3.5.1.201404300702-RELEASE
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 99 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2014-08-12 09:05:30.930
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:304)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:700)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4688)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$21(WorkbenchPage.java:3034)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3016)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2976)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2959)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui.actions.ShowDashboardPageAction$1.runInUIThread(ShowDashboardPageAction.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener cannot be found by org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser_3.5.1.201404300702-RELEASE
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 99 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-08-12 09:06:36.823
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!

!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 2 0 2014-08-12 09:06:36.861
!MESSAGE Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

How to resolve this. Any help or reference link will be much appreciated.

Comment: I encounter this issue in STS 3.6.4 for Linux (64 bits) too.
Full STS package downloaded from the website (https://spring.io/tools/sts/all), that includes Eclipse Luna SR1 release (titled "Based on Eclipse 4.4.2").

Answer (score 16):

I also had the same problem. I have STS with following configuration (Help->About Spring Tool Suite) :

```
Version: 3.6.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201411281415
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)
```

Here is what I did -

> 1. Go to Help-> Install New Software
> 2. Added  http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.4 in the textfield "Work with". Click "Add" button. Provide relevant name
>      and press ok button.  Note: I chose mentioned link from [STS Nightly
>      Builds](http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html). Many links for different versions are shown. Choose the
>      link according to your Platform version(mine is Platform: Eclipse Luna
>      SR1 (4.4.1) as shown above).
> 3. Then list is populated(see picture).
>
> [image: Install your Eclipse platform version specific things]
>   4. I selected all the elements in the list and installed all.

For me it worked and hopefully will work for you as well.

Comment: I tried it but not succeeded.. I am using Version: 3.6.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201411281414
Platform: Eclipse Kepler SR2 (4.3.2)
So I choose "for Eclipse Kepler (4.3): http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.3" and installed all elements but use.. :(

Comment: As Eclipse has moved 2 version ahead with Luna Mars, might be update site for Kepler is not being worked upon with same pace as developers will migrate to new versions and try new features. So if its not an absolute requirement to use old version, can I suggest you to use at least STS based on 4.4.1 version. You can downlod from https://spring.io/tools/sts/all

Comment: If so I need to set up again android and all other plugins like Maven, Gradle, Git...etc How its possible to update with out downloading new version..?

Answer (score 8):

If you use Eclipse **Mars 4.5** just go to eclipse config, 
then "Spring" -> "Dashboard" 
then "Use old Dashboard" - switch on.
then "Apply"

it works!

Answer (score 6):

https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3733

"*You are running STS on top of Eclipse Luna? It looks like you used an update site that was created for Eclipse 4.3 or previous versions. The JavaFX components are those for Eclipse 4.3 (and earlier), but not the ones for Eclipse 4.4 (Luna). What update site did you use?
The fix for this would be to re-install the STS components into Eclipse Luna from the 4.4-based update site (mentioned on top of that page) or download a ready-to-use nightly build of STS 3.6.0 based on Eclipse Luna from here:
http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html*"

Comment: The links mentioned are really helpful. Worked for me.

Comment: This is the only solution that makes logical sense. Basically boils down to version incompatibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is going to help, but this error happened  to me on Windows 10. What I did to get rid off the error was to uncompress the zip using 7-zip.

[7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer for hours. Finally the solution:
**Install Oracle JDK instead of Open JDK and the problem is gone.**

Comment: Yeah I installed Oracle JDK only but the problem still there

Answer (score 2):

Go to your eclipse or spring tool suit, check what kind of eclipse..

go to ->> http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS/nightly-distributions.html

find a relevant one for your tool (eg: if yours is eclipse oxygen means copy Oxygen link (http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/nightly/e4.7) ).

then goto your tool -> help -> install new software, add the link,
 just name it anything.
ok it will show the available software updates for you.

select all and install it...
it will ask to restart .. just restart. issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really fixed with 3.6.3, because I have now the same issue after upgrading to 3.6.3-Release.

EDIT: 
But for my solution, after installing I went to "install new software", then I choose link of SpringSource Luna Eclipse Update Site, and then I saw, Dashboard was not installed, and installed it then.

EDIT 2:
I am not able to install, cos eclipse says, there is already a newer version installed.
I really must say, the last versions of STS from 3.5.x, there were often problems when updating sts. And always similar problems, that at least I removed STS and installed a new version then from the cratch ... :-(

Comment: I also had same problem with 3.6.3 version. For solution see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Luna (4.4.2) install:

I was unable to get any of the answers mentioned above to work, but the comment above that mentioned the link ([spring.io/tools/sts/all](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all)) by jplandrain set me on the right path.

## - **Note**:

The first time I attempted all of the below steps, I was still having issues. My final result was a success after reinstalling a fresh install of Luna and repeating the below steps (less the uninstall of previously installed spring software)

1. uninstall all previous spring related software (unless this is your first attempt)
2. restart eclipse
3. double check everything uninstalled
4. restart computer
5. go to link ([spring.io/tools/sts/all](https://spring.io/tools/sts/all)) and copy the below link from under the "Update Sites" section.

   - At the time of this writing (for Luna), it was: "http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/"
6. (Mac) Help -> Install New Software… -> Add…
7. Fill out the name and location sections

   - Name: "Spring Tool Suite"
   - Location: "http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.4/"
   - [image]
8. Select All -> Next

   - [image]
9. Wait...

   10. Choose “Update my installation to be compatible with the items being installed” -> Next -> Next

       - [image]
   11. Choose “Accept the terms of the license agreements” (if you want to proceed) -> Finish
   12. Restart eclipse
   13. Success! (If not, you may want to try doing a fresh install of eclipse)

       - Observe Spring Tool Suite dashboard once it restarts

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved in spring-tool-suite-3.6.3.RELEASE

Comment: Till today issue still remains with freshly downloaded STS 3.6.3. But it can be fixed as per my answer

Comment: Happens also with freshly download STS 3.6.4 on Linux

Answer (score 0):

to solve my problem i do the steps below.

1. menu > Help > installation details.
2. uninstall all spring components.
3. install spring again dragging install button to my eclipse, from this link
   http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tool-suite-sts-eclipse-luna-44.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by Extracting to simple folder named STS Folder . and then run STS.exe with proper location ( like not run from usb and anyother source ) . In short C/D or any Drive with small folder name .

Answer (score 0):

**SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.13 -**

**Step 1**
Go to help --> install new software

[image]

**Step 2**
use link -> https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.13
and download all.

[image]